# Java BigInteger modInverse and modPow

Tags: java, biginteger, modulo

I am trying to understand the behavior of modPow and modInverse of Java's BigInteger class as they do not work as I would expect. Maybe I am missing something simple, so here is a very simple piece of code:

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(5);

BigInteger n1 = new BigInteger(32, 100, new SecureRandom());
System.out.println("n = " + n1);

System.out.println("a^b = " + a.modPow(b, n1) + " ;; (a^b)^(b^-1) = " + a.modPow(b, n1).modPow(b.modInverse(n1), n1));
```

The output I get is:

```
n = 2664021049    (This is a random prime, can change each run)
a^b = 32 ;; (a^b)^(b^-1) = 4
```

Now, I would expect the `4` there in the last line to be `2`, as it is `(a^b)^(1/b) = a^(b*(1/b)) = a`

Should this also work in a modulo field?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(a^b)^(1/b) = a^(b*(1/b))` - that doesn't hold for modular inverses.

Comment: So is there another way that given `(a^b)` and `b` I find `a`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Invert `b` mod `p-1`, not mod `p`. (If `b` isn't invertible mod `p-1`, the problem is unsolvable.)

---

While it is the case that if `x ≡ y (mod p)`, then `x^z ≡ y^z (mod p)`, we *cannot* conclude that `z^x ≡ z^y (mod p)`. For example, by Fermat's Little Theorem,

```
x^p ≡ x (mod p)
```

even though `p ≡ 0 (mod p)`, and `x^0 = 1`.

However, Fermat's Little Theorem gives us a solution. For integers `x` and `y` and a prime modulus `p`, if we can find a multiplicative inverse `z` for `y` mod **`p-1`**, then

```
(x^y)^z = x^(yz)
        = x^(k(p-1) + 1) for some k
        = (x^(p-1))^k * x
```

If `x ≡ 0 (mod p)`, then `(x^(p-1))^k * x ≡ x (mod p)` because both sides are congruent to 0.

If `x !≡ 0 (mod p)`, then we can derive `x^(p-1) ≡ 1 (mod p)` from `x^p ≡ x (mod p)`, and we have `(x^(p-1))^k * x ≡ 1^k * x ≡ x (mod p)`.

Thus, `(x^y)^z ≡ x (mod p)`.

On the other hand, if `y` is not invertible mod `p-1`, then it turns out we can't recover `x` from `x^y`, because there are multiple possible `x` values. For example, with `x = 2, y = 3, p = 7`, we have `x^y ≡ 1 (mod p)`, but `x` could have been `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the confusion comes from, that

```
b.modInverse(n1) == 532804210
```

because **(5 * 532804210) mod 2664021049 == 1**

After this:

```
a.modPow(b, n1) == 32
```

=> 32 ^ b.modInverse(n1) mod 2664021049

=> 32 ^ 532804210 mod 2664021049 == 4

Answer (score -2):

Refer this to understand the behavior of modPow() and modInverse() of BigInteger class.

modPow :

```
BigInteger numOne = new BigInteger("5");
BigInteger numTwo = new BigInteger("20");
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger("3");
BigInteger MP = numOne.modPow(exponent, numTwo);
System.out.println(numOne + " ^ " + exponent + " mod " + numTwo + " = " + MP);
```

modInverse :

```
BigInteger numOne = new BigInteger("7");
BigInteger numTwo = new BigInteger("20");
BigInteger MI = numOne.modInverse(numTwo);
System.out.println(numOne + " ^-1 mod " + numTwo + " = " + MI);
```